# Bootstrap - Fill remaning height of a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap. I want the top div to be of fixed height according to the content and the bottom div to fill out the remaining height of the parent. The total height should be 100%.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div id="test">
        <div>
          Fixed height according to content.
        </div>
        <div class="fill">
          Rest of the height
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid, .row, .col-lg-6, #test{
  height: 100%;
}

.fill {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  height: 100%
}
```

However it seems like the bottom div is exactly 100% and overflows. The idea is also that there will be several columns.

Thanks in advance!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eb8v57pe/4/

Comment: If you want equal height columns, you should look into the css display table/table-cell properties. There are also javascript solutions if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div id="test">
        <div class="header">
          Fixed height according to content.
        </div>
        <div class="fill">
          Rest of the height
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

html, body{
  height:100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-fluid, .row, .col-lg-2{
  height: 100%;
}
#test {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#test > .header {
  display: table-row;
  height: 1%;
}

#test > .fill {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Edited some stuff in the CSS. This is how it's intended to work:
https://jsfiddle.net/eb8v57pe/5/

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `table-row` on both elements as code above, can't guarantee your changes will work properly everywhere.

Table rows and cells always must stretch to table width or height, so this `1%` always give you rest on other rows, keeping height of header at minimal required.

Comment: Oh I see, missed that. By the way, is there anyway to make the bottom div scrollable in case of overflow?